# How to map a React functional component

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am trying to display a single user JSON API result through React.js code. This is my JSON response I get when I do `console.log()`.

`{"id":1,"email":"test.k@gmail.com","mobile":+989898989,"name":"testname K","address":"my address here, India","gender":"1","tagline":"Friendly to all"}`

but when I try to print it as {singleUserDetail.name} it prints nothing. What is the issue here?

```
     const [singleUserDetail, setsingleUserDetail] = React.useState('');
const id = user.id;
console.log(id); //getting id here as 1
const getsingleUserDetails = () => {
    axios
        .get(`http://localhost:3001/user/1`, { withCredentials: true })
        .then((response) => {
                          const singleUserDetail = response.data;

           console.log(response.data); //prints the above json reults in console
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(" error", error);
        });
};

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getsingleUserDetails();
  }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{singleUserDetail.name}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`singleUserDetail` is your state, but you are assigning a new variable inside of the axios function. you should do this instead;

`setSingleUserDetail(response.data)`